# Passing object in programmatic triggered segue?

Tags: swift

I have been reading around quite a bit trying to figure this out. How exactly do you pass an object in a progammatically created segue? I am trying to make the tableviewcell the reason the popover is launched and from all the reading the only way to set the anchor was do to like so below. How do you pass an object in something like this?

Current code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    var deckObject: AnyObject = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! DeckResults
    let cell: victorycellcontroller = winRecord.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! victorycellcontroller
    let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var playersNotesController: PlayerNotesViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("StatWidgetPlayersNotes") as! PlayerNotesViewController
    playersNotesController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
    let popoverplayersNoteController = playersNotesController.popoverPresentationController
    popoverplayersNoteController?.permittedArrowDirections = .Any
    popoverplayersNoteController?.delegate = self
    popoverplayersNoteController?.sourceView = cell.centerpointforpopover
    presentViewController(playersNotesController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us suppose the object you want to pass is `itemToPass`.

Now, In the `PlayerNotesViewController` class, create an object.

```
var yourObject: AnyObject!
```

Now, update your code as shown here:

```
var playersNotesController: PlayerNotesViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("StatWidgetPlayersNotes") as! PlayerNotesViewController
playersNotesController.yourObject = itemToPass
playersNotesController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
```

You will find that the values from `itemToPass` are not available in `PlayerNotesViewController` as `yourObject`.

Comment: Thanks! just need to figure out how to have the specific item from the row selected now! I tried adding a line similar to this before but it was turning up nil.